# Using border-radius to the button

Tags: html, css

Here's my CSS code

```
.btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #efd9ca;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

In here, border-radius works well to the button box. However, when I put border-radius to `.btn` class it does not work. Whats' the reason behind it?

Thank you!!

Comment: Its working on my end, can you please share the html code for this?

Comment: Please attach relevant HTML.

Comment: Since it's the `<a>` element that has the background and padding, I would suppose the border radius should be set on that element instead of the `.btn` element.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
}

.btn a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #efd9ca;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.btn a:hover{
    background-color: #Ff5678;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn"><a>My button</a></button>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think `border-radius` is override from button box so if you want to use `border-radius` from `.btn` class then you need to write `!important` like below:

```
border-radius:10px !important
```

try this it works for you.